# getting UnsupportedMediaException when consuming soap wsdl webservice in jdeveloper

Tags: java, wsdl, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

The error:

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported
> Content-Type: application/xml Supported ones are: [text/xml]  at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:220)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:151)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:299)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:268)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
> at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
> at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)     at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)    at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)    at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getService(Unknown Source)    at
> someClient.SomeClient.main(WaselClient.java:23)

I have created a custom application to consume wsdl and a client to execute webservice. but I am getting above error when running client.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WaselClient waselClient = new WaselClient();
    
    WaselAddressService waselAddressService = new WaselAddressService();
    IWaselAddressService iWaselAddressService = waselAddressService.getBasicHttpBindingIWaselAddressService();
    try {
        
        GetAddressResponseStructure address =
            iWaselAddressService.getIndividualWaselAddress(ItemChoiceType.ID, "999999");
        
        System.out.println("" + address.getGetIndividualWaselAddressResponseDetailObject()
                                       .getWaselAddress()
                                       .get(1));
    } catch (IWaselAddressServiceGetIndividualWaselAddressCommonErrorElementFaultMessage e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    
}
```

I called the wsdl from SOAP UI and Postman, SOAP UI is returning result but Postman is returning 500-Internal Server Error.

Comment: SOAP webservice was returning application/xml for some unhandled exception occurred in web service, exception raised as request payload header contains content-type="text/xml; charset:utf-8" where as SOAP wsdl is accepting only "text/xml". they did not handle this case in their webservice

Answer (score 0):

SOAP webservice was returning application/xml for some unhandled exception occurred in web service, exception raised as request payload header contains content-type="text/xml; charset:utf-8" where as SOAP wsdl is accepting only "text/xml". they did not handle this case in their webservice